# Multiple wars deployment on tomcat8 gives org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found error

Tags: java-8, tomcat8, xerces

I am trying to deploy 3 wars in tomcat 8. All wars need xerces jars as their dependency. But while deployment i am getting javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found error. 
First war gets deployed properly but after that while deploying other two wars i am getting error.
All three wars have xercerImpl-2.11 and xml-apis as their dependency.

```
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:200)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:152)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:232)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:127)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getFactory(Digester.java:470)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getParser(Digester.java:677)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:830)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:387)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Try to mark this dependency in `pom.xml` as `provided` then put this jar files in `$tomcat/lib`. BTW, I prefer to stick with one app for each single tomcat instance.

Comment: Any reason we should stick to one app for each tomcat instance? Also if i am packaging all jars related to a war inside it then why it should conflict with others.
The project that i am talking about is some old project it is not maven. So no question of pom.xml.

Comment: for instance you can control the amount of system resources for the app and IMHO it is easier in management.